# How to scroll  inside HTML table using Selenium Java ?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am automating a process, where I have to read data from an HTML table. I am using Selenium with Java.

My HTML table initially loads only 25 records. Only after scrolling I will get the next 25 records and it goes on. I am able to read data of only the first 25 records. Can someone help me out with Selenium Java code to scroll and get the data of next 25 records, and again scroll to get the next 25 records and also to get the maximum number of rows in the table.

Comment: This blog post : http://blog.varunin.com/2011/08/scrolling-on-pages-using-selenium.html might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

try below code , using javascript executor to get page height then execute a scroll command ,it will keep on scrolling till page height stops changing

```
try {
    long lastHeight = (long) ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return document.body.scrollHeight");

    while (true) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        long newHeight = (long) ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return document.body.scrollHeight");
        if (newHeight == lastHeight) {
            break;
        }
        lastHeight = newHeight;
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```